# Consider the operator $f \to f(\phi(x))$ where $\phi(x)$ is a smooth increasing function. Show when this is a bounded operator on $L^\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Consider the operator $f \to f(\phi(x))$ where $\phi(x)$ is a smooth increasing function. Show when this is a bounded operator on $L^\infty$

The condition is $\phi'(x)>0$. Proof:

Let $\|f\|_\infty=1$ thus the set $A=\{x | f(x)>1\}$ has measure $0$. Now assume that $\phi'(x)>0$ and let $B=\{x|f(\phi(x))>1\}$ Now assume that $B$ has positive measure, then $\mu(\phi(B))=0=\int_B\phi'(x)$ where the last equality follows from $\int_{\phi(B)}1$ and substituting $u=\phi^{-1}(x)$. Is this correct? Is there another way of going about it? This seems interesting as i never knew that $\mu(\phi(A))=\int_A\phi'(x)$

Answer (score 1):

It is correct except that you missed an absolute value sign in the definition of $B$. The equation $\mu (\phi(A))=\int_A \phi'(x)dx$ can be proved by noting that when $A$ is a finite disjoint union of intervals $[a_i,b_i)$ we have $\int  \phi'(x)dx=\sum \phi (b_i)-\phi (a_i)=\mu (\phi (A))$. Extension to a general Borel set $A$ is proved by standard arguments.

Comment: That is a standard argument when $\phi$ is absolutely continuous. I did not know it can be extended to smooth injections. But i see it now if  we assume $u$sub is valid for such functions, which it is. Thank you!